# How to publish a bean via static method in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency, java-memory-model

I'm working on a legacy Spring-Boot application where I would like to use dependency injection with some code that exists outside the application context. One a part of the application comes as a separate JAR-file and cannot be modified. But I am able to modify some classes that are instantiated in that part. Here how I'm planning to do this:

```
class ServiceHolder {
   private static FooService fooService;
   public static FooService getFooService() { return fooService; }
   public static void setFooService(FooService service) { fooService = service; }
}

@Bean
@Profile("production")
FooService fooService() {
   var service = new ProductionFooService();
   ServiceHolder.setFooService(service);
   return service;
}

public class LegacyPojo {
   private final FooService fooService;
   public LegacyPojo() {
       fooService = ServiceHolder.getFooService();
   }
   //.. some business logic
}
```

I'm worried about possible visibility problems when different requests in separate threads will call `new LegacyPojo()` and reach for `FooService` instance.

So my question is: should I declare `ServiceHolder#getFooService` and `ServiceHolder#setFooService` `synchronized` or not?

Comment: Why do you think that you need this ServiceHolder?

Comment: So, today this LegacyPojo looks exactly like this and already making use of ServiceHolder.getFooService right?

Comment: Yes, LegacyPojo looks somewhat like this. I need ServiceHolder to provide a FooService instance to a pojo. I wish I could inject it directly in a place where new LegayPojo is called, but I can't

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of others things you can do that with security, dont you think that you could have the instance of `FooService` into `LegacyPojo` passing it by constructor, it will be less coupled.

Other thing that you can do is to control the instances of `FooService`, you may do it as a singleton, declaring it as a static property on ServiceHolder and not to have a `setMethod`. I think, the way you told, you want a single instance of `FooService`.

Even LegacyPojo being a `Pojo`, you dont need to create a getter for `FooService`.

Once you use `ServiceHolder.setFooService(service);` you may do a implementation like this:

```
class ServiceHolder{
     private static FooService fooService;

     public static void setFooService(FooService newFooService){
          if(fooService== null){
                fooService = newFooService;
          }
     }
}
```

So that way, you will set only the first instance of `FOoService` and it will not be changed, of course you can do any condition to setFooService in `ServiceHolder`

Answer (score 0):

It would work without any synchronization because singleton bean will be instantiated in a critical section inside `synchronized` block. In `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` class there is a method `getSingleton` which, according to the doc:

```
/**
* Return the (raw) singleton object registered under the given name,
* creating and registering a new one if none registered yet.
* ...
*/
```

And at the very beginning of this method, the critical section starts `synchronized (this.singletonObjects)`. So the effect of `ServiceHolder.setFooService(service)` call will be visible to all threads after leaving the critical section.